# Can I bulk change report connections on Strategy Companion Analyzer

Tags: reporting-services, analyzer

A quick one, we are due to change servers soon, and wondered on Strategy Companion Analyzer if there was a way to bulk change the connections rather than having to go into 100's of reports manually and change the Server Name. In this example we are moving to  CHH-BILive server.

[image]

Comment: Which reporting service are you using?

Comment: We create the reports in SSRS 2008 R2 Reports Builder and use Strategy Companion Analyzer to deploy them, the above screenshot is from the latter.

Comment: Ohk. Sorry I don't know how to manage from Strategy Companion Analyzer - but I have played using ReportDatabase from SQL Server!